# how to update column in C# winform with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, winforms, datatable, etl

I'm making a batch program using a mapping table.

The database configuration is as follows.

### original Table # (It has about 100 million rows)

| person_id | A_concept_id | A_source_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000001 | 0 | LP010880A0 |
| 1000001 | 0 | LP010900A0 |
| 1000002 | 0 | LM130130A0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

### Mapping Table (It has a 1:1 matching value corresponding to source_value.)

| target_id | source_value |
| --- | --- |
| 3039312 | LP010880A0 |
| 3002736 | LP010900A0 |
| 3024929 | LM130130A0 |
| ... | ... |

I can't insert the mapping table into the database because I don't want to store the mapping table in the database. So, I am trying to make an ETL batch program with winform.

The method I tried previously was to create a DataTable by using the list of mapping table columns as list.

```
DataTable drugDt = MappingDrug.Drug_mapping_table(); // static DataTable 

        for (int i = 0; i < drugDt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            
            string concept_id = drugDt.Rows[i]["target_id"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            string source_value = drugDt.Rows[i]["source_value"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;

            DBC.DBconnection(this, "CDM");

            
            _Sql = @"UPDATE cdm.drug_exposure
                        SET A_concept_id = " + concept_id + @"
                        WHERE A_source_value  = '" + source_value + "' ";

            
            DBC.Fn_ExecuteNonQuery(_Sql);
            DBC.DB_close();
        }
```

However, it takes 30 minutes to update one column, and if there are 3000 rows in the mappingtable, it takes 90,000 minutes in total.
Is there any way to make the update more efficient?

Comment: Doing this update outside of a DB engine would be slower and inefficient. Why can't you import the mapping table as a temporary table in db, and do this UPDATE from within a plpgsql function?

Comment: Even if you do update using a SP or function, you should do it in chunks[say in blocks of 10k rows], not all rows at once.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran  
My boss wants to hide the mapping table.
As you said, I want to update all at once, but is there a way to process it externally in C#?

Comment: If you create it as temporary table , and after this bulk update, you can delete that temp table. Doing it externally in C# is possible, but as you noticed it will be quite slow.

Comment: By the way, in your above C# code, you should **not** open and close connection within the for loop, do it only once , _outside_ the loop. Also, disable `auto commit` so that you can do one single commit at the end.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran 
It is not that I did not think of bulk updates using temporary tables, but there is a concern that temporary tables will remain in the database if an error occurs during update and a forced shutdown occurs. But thanks to you, I found the problem with this code.
After executing the open and close connection so that it runs only once in the for loop, if it is still slow, it seems to be necessary to bulk update using temporary tables inevitably.
Thank you so much!!!